# getting preseed files onto Ubuntu initrd

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, automated-install

I am trying to set up an automated process for installing/re-imaging some Ubuntu boxes (16.04).  I am working from 
[Automating the installation using preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apb.html) which has a good description of how to construct the preseed file but is a bit terse when it comes to how to deploy it and I am the first to admit that my primary role is not sysadmin :)

I am doing the install over idrac from an ISO on a virtual drive.  I want to preseed as much as possible which seems to imply that I should use initrd.  The install instructions says

> If you are using initrd preseeding, you only have to make sure a file named preseed.cfg is included in the root directory of the initrd

but I have no idea how I would do this -- do I need to alter the ISO?

Comment: Typically for automated install on bare metal installation you would use PXE + tftp, not an ISO.

Answer (score -1):

Russel, the process for installing your preseed.cfg into an iso is outlined [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed/EditIso) for Debian-Installer (which is used by SOME Ubuntu installers (I believe at least the server releases do, but this is not entirely clear/publicized)).

I've been doing this successfully with Debian isos for a while, and recently tried to do same with Ubuntu isos and, like you, hit a wall.

As you wrote, the ubuntu documentation says explicitly you just have to put a preseed.cfg in the initrd root (which for ubuntu server 17.10 amd64 iso, is the root of the gz archive at install/initrd.gz). Preseeding an Ubuntu iso in this way simply doesn't work as advertised by Ubuntu. So far, I have tried this with server and desktop, 17.04 and 17.10 releases. (See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022392/preseed-cfg-installed-in-initrd-root-not-being-recognized-in-ubuntu-installation) for some very relevant details.)

Please advise if you have made any progress on this since December. Thanks!